# When to use CardViews vs tools:listitem when creating RecyclerViews?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, cardview

I came across this code:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
   tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />
```

where tools:listitem was a layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, when creating recyclerviews, when should we choose Cardviews as its items and when should we choose layouts such as the one mentioned above?
What are the advantages one provides over the other or are they the same(Note that the recyclerview_item layout XML doesn't have any Cardview tags, so they aren't atleast literally the same)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tools:listitem` only sets a design-time preview for a list item by providing a specific layout resource, be it a `CardView`-based layout or something different.

You can use `tools:listitem` along with other [tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) attributes and [`@tools/sample`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolssample_resources) resources to emulate components' runtime or compile-time behaviors such as layouts, dummy data, visibility e.t.c.

Those attributes do not affect your app's runtime behavior in any way.

Additionally, you can read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/tools-attributes-hidden-gems-of-android-studio-d7451b194e0b) tutorial on `tools` attributes.

As for cards vs regular layouts, there are some in using cards as containers: cards support elevation, shadows, rounded corners and have a consistent visual style while supporting different content lengths with no additional actions required e.t.c

Personally, I'd use a `CardView`-based layouts in cases where I need to show some list items with straightforward layouts in a platform-consistent way.

Comment: Okay. Now I know what tools:listitem is used for. Could you please tell me when I should use Cardview vs when I should use a normal layout for list/recyclerview items